# How do i give row names just like column names?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using DataGridview to make a Scheduler. I have written days names like Mo,Tu..... I want these value should be on the most left portion of the grid.
The current column index is 0 which should be -1,so that they look familiar with the column names. How do i achieve this?

[image]

This is basically a time table schedule.

I need one more thing as shown in the figure provided by me. I want the selected cells value (blue colored in the figure) of the Gridview. How do i get these values so that i can get the exact time and day selected by the user?

Comment: Q1: No. Q2: Look into the dgv.SelectedCells. You can loop over them to find the selected cells and analyse them..

Answer (score 1):

You can name cells with the `HeaderCell.Value` property, for example:

```
dataGridView.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "Mo";
```

Comment: Note : This will provide the look but not a name.

Comment: When you wish to get the name you can call the property again like `if(dataGridView.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value == "Mo")
{
//Do Stuff
}`

Comment: That would have to go in a loop.. We don't know what the OP want to do with it. So the direct answer would be 'No', no name in the rowcollection.

Comment: The OP will always know which row has been selected, and can therefore always get the HeaderCell Value of it. Aside from this, it looks as if the OP only wants the visuals as opposed to the value, as he specifically stated he wants the words in column index -1

Comment: Yes, which is why you got an +1 from me. But it is worth noting the that is __not__ creating _row names just like column names_.

Comment: Oh right, yes :) Sorry for the misunderstanding in that case! It just about qualifies as a valid substitute.